# Почему не отображается квадрат?

Tags: java

Учу java. Писал код программы, которая создает фрейм и рисует черный квадрат на нём.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Paint extends Canvas implements Runnable {

boolean running = true;

@Override
public void run() {

    while (running){
        //Пометка1
        render();

    }
}

public void render() {

    //Пометка 2
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();

    if(bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();

}

public void start() {
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(paint, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();

    paint.start();

    }
}
```

Если вместо render()  (в коде Пометка 1)  вставить его код (Пометка 2), квадрат не отображается, хотя по логике должно быть всё то же самое. Как это можно объяснить?

Comment: Тем, что в run копируете return из render?

Comment: Сложно представить себе что-то более ужасное, чем `render` в цикле.

Comment: Да, похоже дело в return.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
public void render() {
//Пометка 2
BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
if(bs == null) {
    createBufferStrategy(2);
    requestFocus();
}else{
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
    }
}
```

Сейчас всё равно, где находится код. Return в методе render выводит тебя из него, и ты просто попадал в while, который повторно запускал прорисовку квадрата. Когда же ты вынес его в while, return выводил тебя из самого while, и повторно ничего не запускается.